# Is an ethernet bridge the correct way?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bridge

I want to access a private subnet, is bridging the right way?

### Example

eth0
192.168.178.x

tun0
10.8.0.x

I can access every VPN client with 10.8.0.x. But I want to access devices from eth0 when connected to my VPN.
Is a bridge between eth0 and tun0 the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

It's not even possible. Ethernet interfaces have a link layer (MAC address), `tun` interfaces don't. You can bridge Ethernet to `tap` interfaces.

Apart from that: What is the purpose of a VPN? Usually it is to separate legitimate communication partners from the rest. What is the point if someone just needs to connect to the LAN in order to get privileged access?

Under normal circumstances the only reasonable way is to configure the system as a router. You should block everything from Ethernet to the VPN first and then whitelist accesses you want to allow.

Comment: Reason: I connect to my home network from work, phone, etc. But I want to reach other devices in my private network.